# US robotics USB 56K Modem using Network Admin

Tags: usb-modem

I am trying to add a US robotics USB 56K Modem to my system. If I follow the UBUNTU 18.04 instructions. For Ubuntu, without installing additional software, using NetworkAdmin. The problem is that the CONNECTIONS TAB doesn't appear in the widget. See below from UBUNTU help!!!

```
NetworkAdmin that you can find in System => Administration => Networking, will let you set up the ppp connection in a graphical interface. You have to know your device name, ISP phone number, username and password to set it up. 
Open Network Manager (System => Administration => Network) 
*****Select the Connections tab.***** 
Select Modem Connection 
Choose Properties and fill out the fields. 
Click OK 
Select the DNS tab. 
Click add, enter your DNS address. 
Click Close
```

Comment: Danno17 Did you sort it out? If so, how?